# Python pandas vectorization comparison between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of different lengths.

df1

```
    gene_name   chr start   stop    gene
0   ARNTL   chr11   13376772    13376843    gene_name
1   ARNTL   chr11   13393709    13393956    gene_name
2   PPP4R1  chr18   9595015 9595151 gene_name
3   PPP4R1  chr18   9595015 9595151 gene_name
4   SLC9B1  chr4    103806204   103806485   gene_name
... ... ... ... ... ...
4640    GCDH    chr19   13010281    13010813    gene_name
4641    ARL4A   chr7    12727790    12730558    gene_name
4642    ARL4A   chr7    12727790    12730558    gene_name
4643    SMURF1  chr7    98630659    98630744    gene_name
4644    TSTD1   chr1    161007421   161007865   gene_name
4645 rows × 5 columns
```

d3

```
        chr start   stop    exon    exon_number gene    gene_name
0   chr1    901877  901994  exon_number 1   gene_name   PLEKHN1
1   chr1    902084  902183  exon_number 2   gene_name   PLEKHN1
2   chr1    905657  905803  exon_number 3   gene_name   PLEKHN1
3   chr1    905901  905981  exon_number 4   gene_name   PLEKHN1
4   chr1    906066  906138  exon_number 5   gene_name   PLEKHN1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
243869  chrY    15526615    15526673    exon_number 5   gene_name   UTY
243870  chrY    15522873    15522993    exon_number 6   gene_name   UTY
243871  chrY    15508182    15508852    exon_number 7   gene_name   UTY
243872  chrY    15591394    15591803    exon_number 1   gene_name   UTY
243873  chrY    15590922    15591197    exon_number 2   gene_name   UTY
243874 rows × 7 columns
```

I am trying to iterate through rows of df1 and make comparisons to d3

here is my current code.

```
for r,i in df1.iterrows():
    for row, items in d3.iterrows():
        if i[1] == items[0] and i[2] >= items[1] and i[3] <= items[2] and i[0] == items[6]:
            print(i,items)
```

this gets the job done but takes quite a while to run on so many rows.

I would like to vectorize this but insure as to how best to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging):

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, d3, on=['chr', 'gene_name'])
df = df[(df.start_x >= df.start_y) & (df.stop_x <= df.stop_y)]
```

(btw, it's better to use column names, not confusing column indicies)